# Azure Synapse SQL Pool: Issue in MERGE INSERT UPDATE statement

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a table in Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL POOL.

```
CREATE TABLE table_A
  (
  ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
  ClientID    varchar(10),
  fitrstname  varchar(20),
  lastname    varchar(30),
  phone       varchar(20),
  address     varchar(100),
  milageRun   decimal(18,8)
  CONSTRAINT (PK_table_A) PRIMARY NONCLUSTERED
    (
      ClientID ASC
    )
   )
   WITH
    (
     DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
     HEAP
    )
   GO
```

Now when I am trying to do a MERGE-INSERT-UPDATE the above table using the below syntax

```
  MERGE table_A AS TARGET
    USING table_B AS SOURCE
    ON table_A.ClientID = table_B.ClientID
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET
  TARGET.milageRun = SOURCE.odometerCount
  IF NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT INTO (milageRun)
  VALUES (SOURCE.odometerCount)
```

The above SQL script is throwing two different errors:

```
1. Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
   Merge statements with a WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET] clause must target a hash 
   distributed table.
2. Can not update ID column
```

But the same above query works fine when I use normal On-Prem SQL Server or Azure SQL Database.

In the above example `table_A` is a small table and contains < 1000 data. As per Microsoft recommendation we should use Hash distribution only when there are huge records.

So what could be the best approach?

Secondly, even if I am not updating the `ID` column, why the 2nd error is coming?

Any expert advice would be helpful.

Comment: FWIW, the `MERGE` keyword is [known to have a multitude of bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) (some of which Microsoft has acknowledged and decided won't be fixed) and should be avoided.

Comment: I havent seen the `IF NOT MATCHED` construction before, is that an MS extension?

Answer (score 0):

1. 

```
UPDATE table_A
SET milageRun = SOURCE.odometerCount
FROM table_A AS TARGET
JOIN table_B AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.ClientID = SOURCE.ClientID;
```

2. using a separate UPDATE statement without involving the IDENTITY column

```
INSERT INTO table_A (ClientID, milageRun)
SELECT ClientID, odometerCount
FROM table_B
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_A
    WHERE table_A.ClientID = table_B.ClientID
);
```